Displaying and Editing Related Data in MudBlazor Table - Dropdown Not Showing Options
I have a table that lists exercises, and each exercise can have multiple types associated with it.
These types should be displayed in a dropdown within the table row during editing mode.
I started out with a DataGrid but that did not turn out so good, and I ended up with a lot of extra code, just to figure out that I could not make it work.
Now try out with MudTable and it seems to be a bit more smooth.
I can find nothing about the topic in the documentation.
This is an almost working sample: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GOQSaiGnzCcaxcWa
<MudTable T="GetExerciseTemplateDto" Items="getExercises" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" InlineEdit="true">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Number</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Description</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Types</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Number">@context.Number</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Description">@context.Description</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Types">
            @string.Join(", ", context.Types.Select(t => t.Type))
        </MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
    <RowEditingTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Number">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="context.Number" />
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="context.Name" />
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Description">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="context.Description" />
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Types">
            <Select T="GetExerciseTypeDto" SelectedValues="@context.Types" MultiSelection="true">
                @foreach (var exerciseType in allExerciseTypes)
                {
                    <SelectItem T="GetExerciseTypeDto" Value="exerciseType">
                        @exerciseType.Type
                    </SelectItem>
                }
            </Select>
        </MudTd>
    </RowEditingTemplate>
</MudTable>


@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

        base.OnInitialized();
    }
    
    public List<GetExerciseTypeDto> SelectedTypes { get; set; } = new List<GetExerciseTypeDto>();

    List<GetExerciseTypeDto> allExerciseTypes = new List<GetExerciseTypeDto>
    {
        new GetExerciseTypeDto { Id = 1, Type = "Run" },
        new GetExerciseTypeDto { Id = 2, Type = "Bike" },
        new GetExerciseTypeDto { Id = 3, Type = "Swim" }
    };

    IEnumerable<GetExerciseTemplateDto> getExercises = new List<GetExerciseTemplateDto>
    {
        new GetExerciseTemplateDto
        {
            Id = 1,
            Number = 101,
            Name = "Exercise 101",
            Description = "This is a description of Exercise 101.",
            Types = new List<GetExerciseTypeDto>
            {
                new GetExerciseTypeDto
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Type = "Run"
                },
                new GetExerciseTypeDto
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Type = "Bike"
                }
            }
        },
        new GetExerciseTemplateDto
        {
            Id = 2,
            Number = 102,
            Name = "Exercise 102",
            Description = "This is a description of Exercise 102.",
            Types = new List<GetExerciseTypeDto>
            {
                new GetExerciseTypeDto
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Type = "Swim"
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public class GetExerciseTemplateDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<GetExerciseTypeDto> Types { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetExerciseTypeDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}

I must admit that I have no clue how to solve this problem and I do not find it easy to figure it out by only relying on the documentation and the samples it provides, so I have just been hacking away.
Maybe there is no simple way of solving this, and if that is the case then I am open for a more simple way of solving it, like expanding it in another way than a MudSelect.
Maybe row-detail-view would be a better option ? But then I would somehow use that in both  and  ?

I'd recommend using MudSelect instead of Select for the table.
And using enums or some constant for the selectable options instead of class objects. This simplifies context based binding, especially in a table where you will have multiple rows/items.
Here's an example with my suggestions.
<MudTable T="GetExerciseTemplateDto" Items="_exercises" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Xs" InlineEdit="true">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Number</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Description</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Types</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Number">@context.Number</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Description">@context.Description</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Types">
            @string.Join(",", context.Types)
        </MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
    <RowEditingTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Number">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="context.Number" />
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="context.Name" />
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Description">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="context.Description" />
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Types">
            <MudSelect MultiSelection="true" @bind-SelectedValues="context.Types"> 
                @foreach (var exerciseType in _allExerciseTypes)
                {
                    <MudSelectItem Value="@exerciseType"/>
                }
            </MudSelect>
        </MudTd>
    </RowEditingTemplate>
</MudTable>

@code {
    List<GetExerciseTemplateDto> _exercises;
    List<ExerciseTypes> _allExerciseTypes;
    
    void HandleSelectedValuesChanged(IEnumerable<ExerciseTypes> changedValues, GetExerciseTemplateDto context){
        context.Types = changedValues.ToHashSet();
    }
    
    protected override void OnInitialized(){
        _allExerciseTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ExerciseTypes)).Cast<ExerciseTypes>().ToList();
        _exercises = new List<GetExerciseTemplateDto>()
        {
            new GetExerciseTemplateDto
            {
                Id = 1,
                Number = 101,
                Name = "Exercise 101",
                Description = "This is a description of Exercise 101.",
                Types = new HashSet<ExerciseTypes>
                {
                    ExerciseTypes.Run
                }
            },
            new GetExerciseTemplateDto
            {
                Id = 2,
                Number = 102,
                Name = "Exercise 102",
                Description = "This is a description of Exercise 102.",
                Types = new HashSet<ExerciseTypes>
                {
                    ExerciseTypes.Bike,
                    ExerciseTypes.Swim
                }
            }
        };

    }   

    public class GetExerciseTemplateDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ExerciseTypes> Types { get; set; }
    }

    public enum  ExerciseTypes
    {
        Run,
        Bike,
        Swim
    }
}

Demo MudBlazor Snippet
